# vba- averaging Moving Cells

Tags: excel, vba

First post here and extremely new at VBA.

I'm looking to create a macro that averages that last 4 cells in a row, but the last cell will always be one to the right, as it'll be a new week.

Trying to play around with End(xlright) and here's what i got- though there's obviously an error somewhere:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(End(xlRight).Offset(-4):End(xlRight))"`

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `=AVERAGE(INDEX(1:1,MATCH(1E+99,1:1)-3):INDEX(1:1,MATCH(1E+99,1:1)))`

Comment: Okay, so was I not going in the right direction with the "end" logic?

Comment: You are mixing vba with worksheet formulas.  It does not work like that.

Comment: Okay good to  know i'll look into your answer- thanks so much Scott.

Answer (score 0):

For row #1, without *VBA*

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(A1,0,COUNT(1:1),1,0-5))
```

[image]

So with VBA:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox Evaluate("AVERAGE(OFFSET(A1,0,COUNT(1:1),1,0-5))")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Gary's Student- can you explain to me the Width bit? Confused about the range 0-5 and how it brings back the last 4 (which it definitely does so thank you!) Apologies for me noviceness.